# can't find superclass or interface

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I m using Android Studio now because i have to and i never had such issues with eclipse but anyways i add 3 jars libraries and after i want to generate my apk it gives me this error that i tried to search about it but no luck

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find superclass or interface javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClientFactory: can't find superclass or interface javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClient: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClientFactory: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClientFactory: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.auth.OAuth2SaslClientFactory: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: can't find referenced method 'boolean equals(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor)' in program class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.image_gif: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.image_gif: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.image_gif: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:com.sun.mail.handlers.image_jpeg: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DirectColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.FlavorsComparator: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:there were 298 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: Does it appear with debug build as well or only for release build?

Comment: both of them ..

Comment: This happened to you because you have the minifyEnabled option set to true, so you are getting stripped all those classes from the APK. If you want to minify the APK, then you'll have to add those classes in the proguard-rules.pro file, so the minifier will include them.